# How did Imperial military discipline compare to the Swedish in 1632?

Tags: 17th-century, holy-roman-empire, thirty-years-war

During Albrecht von Wallenstein's second appointment as supreme commander of the Imperial Army, how did the discipline among the Imperial ranks compare to the Swedish under Gustavus Adolphus? Specifically, what about at the time of Lutzen?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: I have found a few sentences on that during my research for this answer (https://history.stackexchange.com/a/58943/42064): "Indeed the Swedish army wes more disciplined towards the population in the beginning but this ceased with time [German Wikipedia]. Whaley [Das Heilige Römische Reich Deutscher Nation, 2014, Bd. I, p. 769 (original in english)] sees a general trend to more civil deads in 1634/35 when the position for negotiations were to be improved, then in the 1620s." Maybe this is a starting point.